# How to create a library with dynamic imports which can be imported by Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am trying to reuse Nuxt.js components from one project in another project. So I created a new project which imports the components needed and then exports them as a npm package.

**npm package (main.js)**

```
import SomeComponent from '../foobar/SomeComponent.vue'

export default {
   install (Vue) {
      Vue.component(SomeComponent)
   }
}

export {
   SomeComponent
}
```

**npm package (webpack.config.js)**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/main.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist/'),
    chunkFilename: '[name].build.js',
    filename: 'build.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default',
    library: 'MyLibrary',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  }
}
```

Then in my new Nuxt.js project I can simply import the npm package and the components will be installed automatically. While this works fine when not using any code splitting it will throw an error when trying to use dynamic imports in the `SomeComponent.vue` file.

When adding dynamic imports in my component like so `import(/* webpackChunkName: "mapbox" */ 'mapbox-gl')` the chunks will be created but when running Nuxt in development mode I always get the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 1 failed.

Nuxt does not find the created chunk files. I tried playing around with `publicPath` but I don't get what path would be the right one for Nuxt to be able to access them?

Comment: Hey Chris, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just ended up using a different approach :-/